# Can not extract value in SOAPUI property transfer using xPath and namespaces

Tags: xpath, soapui, xpath-2.0

I try to extract value from xml in *Property Transfer* I use xPath:

```
declare namespace S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
declare namespace ns7="http://schemas.BIGBANK.pl/" xmlns="http://schemas.BIGBANK.pl/"

/S:Envelope/S:Body/ns7:Document/ns7:QueryIPR/ns7:IPIList/ns7:PI/ns7:PI/ns7:cId/
```

and i get error:

`cId    [net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string]`

I set source of transfer as previous step (that return valid XML), property *Response* and path language *XPath*

have no idea how to fix it in SoapUI (in pure java it is much more easier)

Comment: What does the source XML look like (minimal example) ?

Comment: Remove the trailing slash from your XPath. The error is telling you that the expression is unfinished.

Comment: Did you try above solution? otherwise provide sample xml.

Comment: My mistake. In second line I have `xmlns="http://schemas.BIGBANK.pl/"` and that was interpreted. After remove it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my mistake 
At the second line I have:

```
declare namespace ns7="http://schemas.BIGBANK.pl/" xmlns="http://schemas.BIGBANK.pl/"
```

And if you work with pure XML it is OK attribute set. But in SoapUI it should be:

```
declare namespace ns7="http://schemas.BIGBANK.pl/"
```

An now it works fine.